# java.lang.object cannot be converted to (selfmade class)

Tags: java, object, incompatibletypeerror

I'm new to java, just about to finish programming fundamentals at uni, so I'd appreciate thorough explanation of any answers. Thanks. Also by the way I am using BlueJ as part of my university training so that might be relevant.

Anyway, here's the problem; I made a text adventure for one of my assignments, and it was very procedural designed, so I decided to revamp it afterwards into a more object oriented program. I think all you need to know about are 4 class'
(some unimportant bits are left out otherwise this would be pages long but if you think they are important let me know);

inventory

```
static room room;


public inventory(room room)
{
    this.room = room;
}

public static room getRoom()
{
    return room;
}
```

room

```
ArrayList <object> objects = new ArrayList <object>();
public ArrayList getobjects()
{
    return objects;
}
```

object

```
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
public ArrayList getNames()
{
    return names;
}
```

textparse (textparse has a textparse method)

```
public static void textparse(String line)
{
    if (line.indexOf(" ") != -1){
        int space = line.indexOf(" ");
        noun = line.substring(space + 1, line.length()).toLowerCase();
        verb = line.substring(0, space).toLowerCase();
    }
    else
        verb = line;
    verbparse();
}
```

Here's the problem; room has an arraylist of objects which are present in it, object has an arraylist of names they can be called by the player. This is my code to attempt to check whether the noun recognized earlier by the textparse class matches any of the objects' names. This is in the textparse class by the way;

```
public static object nounparse()
{
    for (int counter = 0; counter < inventory.getRoom().getobjects().size(); counter++)
    {
        object current = inventory.getRoom().getobjects().get(counter);
        if (current.getNames().contains(noun)){
            return current;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

It returns the error 'incompatible types:java.lang.Object cannot be converted to object' referencing this line

```
object current = inventory.getRoom().getobjects().get(counter);
```

I'm not sure why it thinks that the output of this is an Object, but due to my limited experience in the field I'm not even sure what an Object is besides a general classifier of a instance of a class. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Classes should be uppercased in Java.  Do you mean `Object` when you say `object`?

Comment: Unless you want all inventory to be in the same room, don't make room static

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a generic parameter. Your `getRooms()` should return `ArrayList<object>`, if that's your desired behavior.

Also, you should really rename your `object` into something else, like `Thing` and `Item`, or it may cause confusion, typo, wrong reads (i.e. you may later think you wrote **O**bject not **o**bject), etc. All class names are also recommended to be written in *Big Camel Case*.

### Further readings

Java Generics: [Java Generics Tutorial at Oracle.com](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)

Java naming convention: (too lazy to find one, see the answer of @DanielWiddis)

Comment: Thanks that worked. Now I feel stupid but at least its sorted. Yeah you are right about the naming scheme but I completely forgot Object was a thing before I started this program. Also I haven't heard of this rule regarding camel case with class names before, but now that you mention it it makes sense. It must be why my lecturer told us not to have capital letters at the start of our method names. Thanks for your help and information and sorry if it was a extremely trivial.

Answer (score 0):

The specific source of your error is a downcast.  The return type of `inventory.getRoom().getobjects().get(counter)` appears to be [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).  An `ArrayList` is of type `Object` in Java, but your lowercase `object` appears to be a new class definition that is not a superclass or interface for `ArrayList`. You could refer to it as an `ArrayList` or `List` or `Collection` or `Object` (note the capitalization), but you are trying to assign it the type `object`.

For more information on using superclass types, search for tutorials on Java inheritance.

If your object type really was compatible with the `ArrayList` you could type cast it to the `object` type, like:

```
object current = (object) inventory.getRoom().getobjects().get(counter);
```

However, I seriously doubt that will work in this case and is almost certainly not what you intend; don't play with typecasting unless you know what you're doing. :)  I only offer this for you to do more research on typecasting to understand it better.

Also, you need to take a quick look at [java coding conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) regarding capitalization of class names and use of camelCase for variable and method names; it'll make your code more readable.